# How to get user from relation using Parse Javascript for android app

Tags: javascript, android, parse-platform

I would like to retrieve a stored user with Parse in javascript in a relation.
So, i have a list of sportevents and in each sportevent there is a user (as a relation from Parse database).
So, i get the list of sportevents.
And i tried to get the user with this javascript code:

```
var user = sportevents[i].get("user").relation("_User");
```

I also tried the simpliest way:

```
var user = sportevents[i].get("user");
```

also tried:

```
var user = sportevents[i].relation("user");
```

But nothing seems to work.

the entire code for my function is:

```
query.find({
  success: function(sportevents) {
        var userIds = [];

      //On recupere les identifiants des evenements sportifs
      for (var i = 0; i < sportevents.length; ++i) {
          var user = sportevents[i].get("user").relation("_User");
          userIds[i] = user.id;       
      }

      var queryPush = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);
      queryPush.containedIn("userId", userIds);

      Parse.Push.send({
          where: queryPush,
          data: {
            alert: "Giants scored against the A's! It's now 2-2."
          }
        }, {
          success: function() {
            // Push was successful
          },
          error: function(error) {
            // Handle error
          }
        });

    },
  error: function(error) {
      console.error("Error finding sport events " + error.code + ": " + error.message);
  }
```

I read a lot of times the Parse Doc but nothing seems to fit to this use case.

Thanks a lot for any help.

Sebastien

Comment: Nobody had the same problem or did the same thing please?

Comment: I think that i have to include query.include("_User"); but i can't manage to get the user later...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the parse facebook team (especially Joseph Tuấn Anh Phan), the answer is:

To load the relation you must use query() on the the Parse.Relation object like so:

```
var query = new Parse.Query("SportEvent");
 query.find({
 success: function(sportEvents) {

 for (var i in sportEvents) { 

var userRelation = sportEvents[i].relation("user"); 
userRelation.query().find({
 success: function(users) { for (var j in users) {
 console.log(users[j].id); } } }); } 
}, error: function(error) { console.log(error); } })
```